# Swipe-to-Delete on rightest UITableViewController inside UIPageViewController

Tags: uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

Looks like `UIPageViewController` prevent `UITableView` to get touch events. My table view is placed in rightest page, so there is no potential problem to recognize gesture.

Is there any solutions of this problem?

Comment: @ChristopherRivera not found any solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your `UIPageViewController`'s  `viewDidLoad` function.

```
if let myView = view?.subviews.first as? UIScrollView {
    myView.canCancelContentTouches = false
}
```

Comment: This pretty much fixes the problem. At least to some extent. I have two side by side table views and this made it such that very accurate gestures inside these table views trigger editing to start. Gestures outside the table views will scroll the page view controller. This should probably be accepted as the correct solutions. Quickest and best/only solution I found to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this third party library which will allow the swipe gesture of the menu to have president over the uipageviewcontroller swipe

https://github.com/WinterKirk/MKSlidingTableViewCell

the important thing is that your whole view shouldnt only have these kind of cells cause then the uipageviewcontroller wont be able to swipe

but it works great in situations where you lets say have an image and comments under it and people should be able to delete the comments but swipe to the next pic on all other cells